# Movie about a hotel staff witnessing human organ transplant in one of the rooms

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie back in 2006. It could have been released before that date.
I think it is a British movie (not Hollywood). Colored.

The one scene I remember is a lady (prostitute) walking out of the hotel lobby heading to the exit. She talks to the staff to tell him something like:

> There is something wrong with the toilet in room #XYZ

I am not sure if she mentions a room number or not, but in case she did, I can't remember the number. I used XYZ as an example.

The staff asks here something about her identity or why she was there and she answers something like:

> I am not supposed to exist

Then the guy goes to the room and finds the toilet blocked by a human organ (maybe a heart, or kidney).

Later in the movie, we learn that the room was used as an operation room to remove organs from a man, who later is shown very sick. I am not sure if he dies or not.

Comment: If you're heart had been flushed down the toilet, you'd be more than "very sick"...

Comment: The "very sick" guy was suffering from a butcher-operation and was missing one of his kidneys. The heart belonged to another victim that we don't see or know about in the movie. @IMSoP

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's [Dirty Pretty Things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Pretty_Things_(film)):

> Dirty Pretty Things is a 2002 British drama film directed by Stephen
>   Frears and written by Steven Knight, a drama about two immigrants in
>   London.
>
> Okwe is an illegal Nigerian immigrant to the United Kingdom who drives
>   a cab in London during the day and works at the front desk of a hotel
>   at night.
>
> A prostitute known as Juliette, who plies her trade in the hotel,
>   informs Okwe about a blocked toilet in one of the hotel rooms. He
>   fishes out the blockage and finds a human heart. The manager of the
>   hotel, Juan, runs an illegal operation at the hotel wherein immigrants
>   swap kidneys for forged passports. After learning of Okwe's past as a
>   doctor, Juan pressures him to join his operation as a surgeon, but
>   Okwe refuses.